# Ruby on Rails rspec runs tests succesfully, but Guard + Spork doesn't find methods for Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, devise, guard, spork

I tried to add a few tests to my Ruby on Rails -application. When I run them on command line using command rspec, it runs fine:

```
Finished in 0.87603 seconds 3 examples, 0 failures
```

When starting guard, it runs them fine for the first time as well. It gives this kind of message even though I'm not using minitest:

```
/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/minitest-4.7.5/lib/minitest/unit.rb:1037:in `block in process_args': invalid option: --drb (OptionParser::InvalidOption)
```

I haven't configured to use MiniTest, so I guess there might be something wrong with my configuration files?

However, when I make changes to my user_pages_spec.rb and save, which triggers Guard to run the tests, it gives this kind of error:

```
Running tests with args ["--drb", "-f", "progress", "-r", "/home/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/guard-rspec-2.5.0/lib/guard/rspec/formatter.rb", "-f", "Guard::RSpec::Formatter", "--failure-exit-code", "2", "spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb"]...

Failures: 
1) 
User pages signup page 
     Failure/Error: before { visit new_user_registration_path }
     ActionView::Template::Error:
       undefined method `devise_error_messages!' for #<#<Class:0x00000006b18248>:0x00000006b226f8>

2) 
User pages signup page 
     Failure/Error: before { visit new_user_registration_path }
     ActionView::Template::Error:
       undefined method `devise_error_messages!' for #<#<Class:0x00000006b18248>:0x000000066de560>
```

Basicly not finding those methods running the same tests the second time. Tests I run for another page which contains only static content works fine.

1. Here are some files:

   - Gemfile: http://pastebin.com/bHgxXYZ3
   - Guardfile: http://pastebin.com/Rnhz2tsJ
   - spec_helper: http://pastebin.com/Jpvu3k2Q
   - .rspec: http://pastebin.com/B0bzmE0n

If something's missing, just give me a note. Thanks for helping :)

Answer (score 0):

Do you also have these errors when starting spork and then running your specs (without Guard)?

For the MiniTest error message, be sure that you don't have a `test/` folder in your project.

Comment: Yeah, I'm getting these errors without Guard as well. Would've been a good idea to clarify that to title as well.